# Python Max Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

How does the max function work when items in a list are not of the same type?

For example the following code returns [1,'3']

```
max([1,52,53],[1,'3']) => [1,'3']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python2, the default comparison for objects of different types is to compare using the *id* of their types (obtained by casting the object pointers to integers).  Here a link to the source:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/object.c#l757

On my build, here is the ordering of types:

```
>>> sorted([bool, int, float, long, list, tuple, dict, str, unicode])
[<type 'bool'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'list'>, <type 'long'>,
 <type 'dict'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'tuple'>, <type 'unicode'>]
```

Numbers (except for complex) have compare methods that allow cross type comparison based on numeric value (i.e. a float can be compared with an int).

The *None* object is special.  It compares less than everything else.

To see it all put together, use *sorted* to see the ordering:

```
>>> sorted(zoo)
[None, -5, -5.0, 0, 0.0, -0.0, False, True, 10, 10.0, 11.5, {},
 {'abc': 10}, {'lmno': 20}, [], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, [2, 3]],
 '', u'', 'alpha', u'alpha', 'bingo', 'cat', (), (1, 2), 
 (1, 2, 3), (1, (2, 3)), u'bingo', u'cat']
```

Comment: Thanks!
But comparing: [1]<(1) returns false. Any idea why?

Comment: @Sagar, note that `(1)` is actually an int. According to Python syntax, you have to have a comma to distinguish it as a tuple, so try `[1] < (1,)`. Still, list and tuple are objects of different type, so presumably they'll be compared using the id of their types.

Comment: Note that `sorted(zoo)` looks unsorted because sorting of different types is ambiguous:  
`str < tuple < unicode < str`.  
Example: >>> `'' < () < u'' < ''`  
Result: `True`

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2 objects of different types are compared <s>by type's string representation</s> using special logic.  See Raymond's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10227493/406693) for details.

In Python 3 this code will raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
    max([1,52,53],[1,'3'])
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't correct.  The default comparison does not use the type's string representation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is "type's string representation"?

Comment: Not exactly by name but similarly obsure.

Answer (score 3):

It does [whatever the `>` operator does](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__) for the two elements.