# Python 2.x sorted puzzlement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a partially sorted tuple in Python 2.x.

Why Python reverse it instead of sort it?

```
>>> data = (u'a', (1,), 'b ', u'b', (2,), 'c ', u'c', (3,), 'd ', u'd', (4,), 'e')
>>> sorted(data) == list(reversed(data))
True
```

I look forward to Python 3.

Comment: Is this an actual question, or just a way to editorialize about a quirk in Python 2.x?  You know that this is because it is silly to compare different types; in Python 3.x you will get an exception for trying it.  Any time you push the boundaries of defined behavior like this you can expect to find odd quirks, and I think you know it: "I look forward to Python 3."

Comment: I was surprised because I am relying on unique "groupby(sorted(..))" for long time. I came to it when I answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227074/python-max-function Yes, it was more surprise than a question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It fails because the sorting algorithm depends on a total ordering of the elements, which implies transitive `<`.

The ordering of unicode strings, tuples, and strings isn't transitive:

```
>>> a = 'x'
>>> b = (1,)
>>> c = u'x'
>>> a < b
True
>>> b < c
True
>>> a < c
False
```

I.e., there exists no valid sort for your list.  At least not with the default comparator.

Comment: Deestan: Thanks for the sentence **sorting depends on transitive "<"**. The worst for me is think of `a, b, c = 'x ', (1,), u'x'` `assert a < b < c < a`. I found many exact conclusions in your answers.